# Download the GWT Developer Plugin For Firefox - cannot install plugin update

Tags: gwt, firefox-addon

I have GWT 2.3 installed; Today I tried to update the FF dev plugin but since it was updated it says

**"This add-on will be installed when Firefox is restarted"**

... but each time I restart FF I can see the same note :( So restarting does not make any effect I tried more than 5 times yet :S Before the update attempt all worked fine.

The plugin link is https://dl-ssl.google.com/gwt/plugins/firefox/gwt-dev-plugin.xpi but maybe the plugin version is somehow is not for my GWT 2.3? I am not pretty sure here :S

So my question is can I rollback the new fail installed plugin or what should I do to restore my previous FF dev plugin?

Comment: Just a note to say that the browser plugin will work with any version of GWT. The protocol they use to communicate with each other is stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need more information to properly answer.  But I'm going to assume you are using Firefox 11 and the browser plugin won't install.  You can install the GWT plugin for FF11 from here: http://acleung.com/gwt-dev-plugin-ff11.xpi

Google tends to lag behind by a few weeks when new Firefox releases come out as the plugins have to go through proper testing before they are pushed to the official "missing plugin" page.  To get the latest plugin when a new version of Firefox comes out, check out the [Google Groups for GWT](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/topics), as Alan Leung (a GWT dev) will post the latest builds within a day or so of release.

Comment: Thank you I guess it is the thing :) All works now. I am using not the latest FF but 3.6 so what plugin archives should I look for to install a proper plugin according to my web browser version? I couldn't find any official resource :S Give me some tips please

Comment: ... I mean where should I look for if I need GWT dev plugin for IE 7 for example?

Comment: You should just be able to point your brower to the [MissingPlugin](http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin/MissingPlugin.html) page and it will download the proper one.  Even if you are using GWT 2.2, using the latest plugin should work without issue.

Comment: OK, but why in my case I had to download the ff plugin from another source like http://acleung.com/gwt-dev-plugin-ff11.xpi?

Comment: If you check out this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/311b8093d336ac6a/ you'll see that they get a build of the GWT plugin within a few days of new FF releases.  But getting them pushed to the Missing Plugin page takes longer (a few weeks) for some reason, I really don't know why.  New FF releases require new GWT plugin builds because they have to be compiled against the specific libraries used for that release of FF.